# v-show doesn't hide elements until I mount Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I `createApp` and `mount` it to `<div>`, which is just under `<body>`.
I `mount` at just before `</body>` because the `<div>` have to exist before I `mount` to it.

My model's property is `false` so the elements with `v-show` should not be shown.

What happens is:

1. `<body>` and `<div>`, which includes the elements with `v-show`, are loaded.
2. They are all shown even though I don't want to see the elements with `v-show`.
3. Vue hide the elements with `v-show`. At last, it's OK.

How can I show properly from the first sight?

I'm using Vue3 on Chrome.

Comment: please share the whole code

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding the `v-cloak` directive to the div and the following style

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

v-cloak docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak